# Image drawing tools (that aren't Photoshop) that work in the sRGB colorspace

Tags: tools, image, color

I'm looking for a way to create sRGB raster images. Now, I could use Inkscape and just have it render to a raster format, but are there any image drawing tools other than Photoshop that work in sRGB?

Here's what I want to be able to do more specifically. Let's say the image is all one color. I want to be able to pick color 0x808080, which is in the sRGB colorspace. I want the file to write an image where every pixel is 0x808080. And then, when I read it, I can tell OpenGL that it's sRGB color data, so it will treat the 0x808080 color has being from the sRGB colorspace.

The important part is that, when I'm selecting colors in the tool, the colors I'm selecting are from the sRGB colorspace.

Comment: I'm pretty sure GIMP uses sRGB as well or you could certainly set it up with color management. But is this really gamedev related?

Comment: @bummzack: The same way that questions about Max, Maya, and Blender are gamedev related. I need to test my sRGB code, and to do that, I need to be able to make an image that I know is in sRGB.

Comment: Fair enough. Could you elaborate a bit on the question? Do you want your image to contain an sRGB color profile? What platform are you working on? What image-format do you want to read/write?

Comment: @bummzack: See my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sRGB is the default color space for most of todays operating systems. From [Wikipedias entry about sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB):

> ... one can generally assume, in the absence of embedded profiles or
>   any other information, that any 8-bit-per-channel image file or any
>   8-bit-per-channel image API or device interface can be treated as
>   being in the sRGB color space.

What that means is: Unless you're using a color managed application (eg. Photoshop) where you're specifically using a profile that's different from sRGB, you will actually work in the sRGB color-space. So if you're using an application without color-management (eg. [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)), you will work in sRGB color-space.

As I mentioned in my comment, the [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) might be a good candidate for your needs (it also uses sRGB as default color-space, but does support color managment if you need to convert from one color-space to another).